# OutOfMemory caused by Buttons background

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I have a list with buttons on each row. Buttons in my application use custom theme with custom drawables (about 0.5Kb png each). 
Users complain of OutOfMemory errors which appears several times per week.

The first idea was that Buttons load BitmapDrawables and do not recycle them. So It leads to exceeding Native memory. 
To test it I’ve changed my drawables by bigger images about 300Kb(jpgs).
Tested on different devices Android version 2.1-2.3.x

**What I saw:**

1. Only one instance of the Bitmap loads and uses for each button. The Native Image id is the same for each bitmap.
2. When I rotate the device list redraws and the native image id changes.
3. After several rotations of the screen the OutOfMemmoryError occurred!

So, it follows to “nobody call recycle for background of buttons”.

To check the recycle can help to solve the problem in onPause method I retrieve Bitmap which is used for background and recycle it myself.  OutOfMemmory does not occur anymore.

The task to recycle each drawable which was used by Views scare me. I cannot believe android has
that kind of issues!

Is there a solution easier then to call recycle for each drawable?

Comment: try to recycle your bitmaps , refer docs about how to load large bitmaps efficiently : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Also read [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: Thx but I've read that pages already. There is anoither kind of problem. I don't load any resource myself. I use Themes with custom Drawalbes for Views like Buttons, EditText, CehkcBoxes and so on...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best solution is to avoid usage of drawables for Buttons if it is possible.